How to calculate the mean percentage return of an stock e.g. Apple?
I am using Alpha Vantage API for the first time. In the Alpha Vantage documentation there is an "Alpha Intelligence" section with functions I am looking for like the 'mean' function.
To use the "Fundamental Data" module I used this code, which gave me the desired results:
pip install alpha_vantage
from alpha_vantage.fundamentaldata import FundamentalData
API_key = my_key
fd = FundamentalData(key=API_key, output_format='pandas')
data = fd.get_income_statement_annual('AAPL')
data[0]


To use the "Alpha Intelligence" module I tried to adapt this code but it didn't work:
pip install alpha_vantage
from alpha_vantage.alphaintelligence import AlphaIntelligence
API_key = my_key
ai = AlphaIntelligence(key=API_key, output_format='pandas')
data = ai.get_analytics('AAPL')
data[0]

I was expecting a table of values showing the min,median,max,mean etc.
This was the result:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'alpha_vantage.alphaintelligence'


There is no "alphaintelligence" module in this Python package. https://github.com/RomelTorres/alpha_vantage/tree/develop/alpha_vantage

Ohh, it's mentioned here though: https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/, would I be able to use it?

OK but this is an http API, sorry but i dont read whole docs. Send either link with line or a section.

Sure there are examples
